# Prove that the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , $f(x) = x*|x|$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I needed help proving this

This is what I tried, I broke it into two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$

Case 1 $x>0$

```
Injectivity
```

$|x|=x$

$f(x) = x^2$

$f(x)$ is a injection if $f(x)$ = $f(m)$ then $x=m$

$x^2 = m^2$

$x=m$ since $x>0$

```
Surjectivity
```

for every $x∈R$

$f(√x) = x $ therefore it is surjective

I needed help proving the case $x<0$

Comment: Don't forget the case $x = 0$. (By the way, I can't resist suggesting defining $g(0) = 0$, and $g(y) = y/\sqrt{|y|}$ for all $y \ne 0$, so that $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y \ne 0$, and $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \ne 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$, it follows that $g$ is the inverse function of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. But I should probably be taken out and shot for this!) :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to view $$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x^2 &x < 0\\x^2&x \ge0\end{cases}.$$ So if z $<$ 0 , then z = -x$^2$ = -x (x) for some x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. And we proceed as you did.

Comment: Am i allowed to do f(sqrt(-x)) like the answer below suggested? i thought sqrt(-x) would give a complex number

Comment: if x $<$ 0, then -x $>$ 0.

Comment: Oh yea thats right.

Comment: so for the injectivity when -x^2 = -m^2 it would become x=m?

Comment: Would it be right if I did like this? sqrt(-x^2) = sqrt(-m^2) = abs(-x) = abs(-m) since x<0 --x = --m, therefore x=m

Comment: @Rufyi yes. that proves subjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for $x\le 0$ you have that $f(x)=-x^2$.

Comment: Yea I know but when i make it -x^2 = -m^2, it becomes x^2 = m^2, but since x<0 shouldn't i take the answer where x=-m? showing that they are not equal or do i still take x=m?

Answer (score 0):

For negative $x$ consider $f(\sqrt -x)$ and go from there.